# Cloning fedora 13 across multiple machines

Tags: fedora, cloning

I want to Install the same mirror of fedora across multiple desktops, are there any cloning tools available for this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately many tools still don't support ext4. You're probably best off looking at using kickstart or a deployment tool such as cobbler.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [mondo](http://www.mondorescue.org/)

one tool which you use [Revisor](http://revisor.fedoraunity.org/)